# MySql How to separate a telephone field in one table into prefix / number in two separate tables?

Tags: mysql

I have this requierment: From Customers table –return the prefix for phone numbers. I tryed with strings as by splitting the fullname into first/last name but it works only the one for the number.
The full nb format is (258) 1231456

Comment: Can you please explain/add to question, little more detailed. You have  `varchar` field like `(258) 1231456` and you need to select only `258`?

Comment: If the prefix is always in the parenthesis you can apply substring and charat methods. 
substring(charat('('), charat(')'))

Answer (score 1):

Base from what understand you can use substring(string,position,length) for example

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(phonenumbercolumn,1,3) AS prefix 
FROM customer;
```

Comment: in that case it returned `(25` And wahat in case when there is (1), or (333) as prefix or even (+48 222)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '(258) 1231456' org,
   TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM '(258) 1231456'), ')', 1)) prefix,
   TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM '(258) 1231456'), ')', -1)) number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function SUBSTRING_INDEX which does a nice job of splitting a string using a character delimiter. So in your case you use ')' as a delimiter and return everything to the left. That way it doesn't mater if the number is like (+48 222) – or like (333). Note the number 1 indicates the first appearance of your delimiter so you have to be careful if you have so many ')' chars.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('(258) 1231456', ')', 1);
```