# how to do sum,subtract functions in Group_Concat in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am generating a report to show outstanding Fee Like which Fee Type,How much amount is Fixed for that Fee Type, How Much Amount Paid for that Fee type and finally Balance Amount to be paid for that fee Type.

Here i am pulling data from 5 tables like Class Names from Classes table, Roll no & Student Name from admissions table, Fee Types from Feevars table, amount fixed for fee type from studentfees table, and finally amounts paid for fee types from fee collection table.

I am able to generate the partial results by mentioning the fee type names in select statment by summing and subtracting operations.

Here is the full database and my query producing the result. plz look **@ [mysql query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a26c7/1%2a%2a)
in the select statement i have mentioned the fee types manually.
But i want to generate the result without mentioning the  Fee type as Column names.

For this i did one thing, i had taken all the fee types into a sql variable
like this

```
set @sqlList = null;SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('tsf.', Replace(FeeName,' ',''))) INTO @sqlList FROM tbl_feevars;
```

this will result all the Fee types into single line as column names.
And Finally I have written code to produce output what i am expecting, but i am getting error like **Error Code 1064: You have error in your sql syntax.**

This is My final code

[**Expected Output Code**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a26c7/2)

Please anyone tell me, what is error in my sql query. And suggest me if any?? other way to do this report.

Answer (score 1):

What is Your desired output ?

I have made that working in this didle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a26c7/15

i Think, that @ is not good... moreover, You want to use arrays... there's no such thing as arrays in MySQL You have to use `LOOP` to simulate array or `TMP TABLE`. See this question with good answer 4u:

[How can I simulate an array variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: thank you @jaczes for your early response, But my expected output is display each Fee type, Fixed amount for Fee type, Paid amount for Fee type and Balance amount to be paid

Comment: see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a26c7/16 there You do have content of `@sqlList`, `@sqlList1` - probably You wil have to do that in loop

Comment: You have to be more specyfic when You will set `@sqllist`

Comment: after modified by you now getting result into @sqlLsit=tsf.AdmissionFee,tsf.SplFee,tsf.TutionFee,tsf.ComputerFee,tsf.Stationary,tsf.Transport,tsf.Hostelfee,tsf.Lab,tsf.Library,tsf.Miscell

Comment: and also for @sqlList1=tsf.AdmissionFee,tsf.SplFee,tsf.TutionFee,tsf.ComputerFee,tsf.Stationary,tsf.Transport,tsf.Hostelfee,tsf.Lab,tsf.Library,tsf.Miscell

Comment: but i want @sqlList1= tfc.AdmissionFee,tfc.SplFee and so--

Comment: Sorry i did'nt seen, @sqlList,@sqlList1 resulting correct output

Comment: could you tell me how can i take the comma separated values into each variable, Is it possible in sql query? As I am generating the @sqlList= SUM(tfc.AdmissionFee),SUM(tfc.ComputerFee),SUM(tfc.Hostelfee),SUM(tfc.Lab),SUM(tfc.Library),SUM(tfc.Miscell),SUM(tfc.SplFee),SUM(tfc.Stationary),SUM(tfc.Transport),SUM(tfc.TutionFee)

Comment: See this :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: and this - my post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719170/mysql-how-to-separate-a-telephone-field-in-one-table-into-prefix-number-in-two/17719466#17719466